# How to allow only one user in a group in sshd_config

Tags: permissions, configuration, sshd

I've just changed the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file on a server, where I want to deny all users except for one in a specific group. This is because I am in the disallowed group myself, but as the server's maintainer I want to be able to access it through ssh.

So my problem is that, as it says in [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html), the order of processing rules is *"DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups"*, which (if I'm understanding this correctly) makes it impossible to do something like:

```
DenyGroups student
AllowUsers myself
```

because the `DenyGroups` is more important than the `AllowUsers`.

I have also tried to exclude myself from the `DenyGroups` by adding a specific `Match User myself`:

```
DenyGroups student
Match User myself
    AllowUsers *
```

But that did not have any effect either, despite the manual saying *"the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file"*.

How would I go about disallowing the whole group of `student`s except for `myself`?

Comment: I think you have to create a new group and add `myself` to new group and grant to new group.

Comment: Would there be no way to do this without creating a new group just to evade this? I'd think there must be a way to do this without creating special groups like that, right?

Comment: ""the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file" .. sure they do: `AllowUsers` overrides `AllowUsers`, `DenyGroups` overrides `DenyGroups`. It doesn't say anything about them overriding different keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @muru has pointed out, when the manual says "the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file", it means you have to use the same keyword, so you can do the following:

```
DenyGroups student
Match User myself
    DenyGroups none
```

This worked for me.